# Differentiability at a point a implies continuity in a neighborhood of a

Tags: calculus

Let f be a map from a open subset U of a normed vector space E to an other F, suppose that f is differentiable at a point a in U. Is f continuous in a neighborhood of a ?

Comment: What is your definition of differentiable ? There are functions which are not continuous but the directional derivatives exist for all directions.

Comment: I mean frechet differentiable not Gateaux

Comment: It's not even true for $E=F= \mathbb R.$

Comment: can you give a counter example please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

False:
$$f(x) = \cases{
x^2& for $x\in\Bbb Q$,\cr
  0& for $x\not\in\Bbb Q$.}$$

Comment: thank you sir : this function is indeed differentiable at 0 but discontinuous at all non zero rational points in every neighborhood of 0

Comment: @sphinx2, also is discontinuous  at irrational points.